# Problem running HTML Upload Form with PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Here is my part of code:

```
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    echo "<form name=\"replace\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"  action=\"\">";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td><input name=\"torepfilename\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$filename\" size=\"20\"></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><b><font color=\"#3498DB\">File already exists. Do you want to replace $filename ? </font></b> <input name=\"replace\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Yes\"></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST['replace'])) {
$copied = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datasheet']['tmp_name'], $filepath);

        echo '<h3><font color="#99CC00">File Uploaded Successfully!</font></h3>';
}}
```

Can anyone help me why second if does not run at all even I click on Yes?

Comment: What debugging have you done, exactly? Did you try moving the `if (isset($_POST['replace'])) {` outside the `if (file_exists($filepath)) {` block? You didn't show how $filepath is populated, but is it possible it's not populated on the postback? Also do you have PHP error logging configured so that errors and warnings show in your log file? And did you then check the log file for information?

Comment: Yes, I tried moving it outside of first if condition, even putting in another PHP tag, but no results.There is no problem with $filepath population, the problem is why ```isset($_POST['replace'])``` doesn't get TRUE even I defined it before?

Comment: Are you certain that's what is the cause? It seems unlikely that it wouldn't be true once the form is submitted. Although just to be sure there isn't a snag, please remove `name=\"replace\"` from the `<form` tag...forms don't have names, that belongs on the input only (which you've already done correctly).

Comment: Done and still no result.
My assumption is that when the whole PHP is executed, it simply jumps over the if condition and continue to run remaining codes and whenever the user click on Yes button, the script will not run again, it's logical also because all if conditions will be checked once and not again after user interaction.

Comment: `whenever the user click on Yes button, the script will not run again`...what do you mean? The form will submit itself back to the same PHP script, so this code _should_ be executed. It _should_ reach the `if (isset...` statement, assuming that `$filepath` is still set correctly when the form is submitted.

Comment: Not sure we need the _whole_ code, but certainly, enough to reproduce the problem. But first, **you** should take the time to debug it properly. Have you actually tested it in detail? i.e. have you done anything like use a debugger, or add some simple logging into your script to see what the variables are, and what path the code takes? instead of being puzzled about what exactly it's doing, just debug it, and then you'll know more accurately where the problem is.

Comment: First of all, I am very new to PHP. Second, Yes, I've been debugging the whole time ever I encountered the issue.
From your last comment, I learned a lesson and maybe found the reason behind it.
You say ```The form will submit itself back to the same PHP script, so this code should be executed. It should reach the if (isset... statement, assuming that $filepath is still set correctly when the form is submitted.``` The thing is that Replace question will only be shown **AFTER** user uploaded a file (means it's in another if condition), so, submitting it back will not help.

Comment: Ok. Then your process is inherently flawed. You need to ask for all info up-front. In your original upload form you should have a checkbox which asks "Is it ok to replace an existing file with this file, if they have the same name"? Then you can decide, on the first submit, what action to take. Uploaded files are not preserved by PHP in their temporary location - once the upload request ends, the file is considered not to exist anymore. Therefore you have to run move_uploaded_file within the same request as the upload occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I just found the proper way to handle the situation.